# Python 3 urllib json AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: json, python-3.x, urllib

I am looping through a list of names that are used to construct a url with JSON values. I'm using json and urllib in Python 3.x to extract JSON values to be used as parameters for for a process in the script. The first iteration everythng works fine but then I get a TYPE error after that.

```
import os, sys, json, urllib.request

info1 = r"https://myurl.services"
info2 = r"/FeatureServer/info/itemInfo?f=pjson"

sList = ['servic_a', 'service_b', 'service_c']

for i in sList:

    url = '{}{}{}'.format(info1, i, info2)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

This works the first time around but the second iteration gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\envs\py3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\envs\py3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    protocol = req.type
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'type'
```

I've tried `data.clear()` and `url.close()` but neither works.

Comment: `with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:` works on first because your url is correct and then it gets overwritten with response of `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` so on next iteration, it tries to do `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` and hence ends up doing `with urllib.request.urlopen(<your http response of previous value>) as url`. To solve this, use something like  `with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as http_response:` and then `data = json.loads(http_response.read().decode())`

Comment: Thank you. I guess it was a dumb oversite but I'll check the answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first iteration, the statement `with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:` does exactly what you want, but overwrites the `url` variable with response of your `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` part. So on next iteration, `url` is `HTTPResponseObject` and `urllib.request.urlopen()` function gets that instead of valid url.